# Allowing only one instance of twitter bootstrap tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Is this possible to limit twitter bootstrap's tooltip to show only one instance?
Example:

```
<div class="d1" title="d1">
    <div class="d2" title="d2">
        <div class="d3" title="d3"/>
    </div>
</div>

$('.d1').tooltip({delay: {show: 1500, hide: 0}, html: true, container: '.content'});
$('.d2').tooltip({delay: {show: 1500, hide: 0}, html: true, container: '.content'});
$('.d3').tooltip({delay: {show: 1500, hide: 0}, html: true, container: '.content'});
```

The problem is that on mouse over for div d3 all tooltips are shown. Is there a way to prevent other tooltips from showing up?

Answer (score 2):

I made a fiddle with a possible work around.
By defining a new "lone-tooltip" the user can achieve a child element's tooltip to be shown on its own by hiding all other tooltips.

This works by using bootstrap's "shown.bs.tooltip", it did not work with "show.bs.tooltip"...

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container:'body',
})
$('[data-toggle="lone-tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container:'body'
})

$('[data-toggle="lone-tooltip"]').on('shown.bs.tooltip',function(e){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').not(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/6jkd0cto/3/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to stop the show event from bubbling up the DOM to the other divs.
See if this works:

```
$('.d3').tooltip({delay: {show: 1500, hide: 0}, html: true, container: '.content'}).on('show', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: 'show' OR 'show.bs.tooltip'?

didn't worked...

There are 2 situations:
1. When mouse move is fast, that on mouse over d3 (and stop) non of the tooltips is visible yet (delay), but after a moment all of them shows up, one after another.
    
2. mouse move is very slow, so when mouser is over d1 first tooltip is displayed, then on mouse move from d1 -> d2, next tooltip is displayed after delay - but the first one doesn't disappear. Then on move over d3, third tooltip is displayed, but others two aren't hidden;

In both cases only the tooltip for d3 should be visible...